# What is the difference between "check something" and "check on something"

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

For example if in answer to the question, "what time does the shop close?" a tourist information officer might say, "I'll check on that for you."

Why wouldn't they say, "I'll check that for you."?

Comment: I think officer would answer: "please, one moment; I check quickly"

Comment: @Carlo_R. That's not what a native speaker would say. To sound more authentic one could say "One moment, please. I'll quickly check[[ on that] for you]."

Comment: @Matt - the officer might not be a native speaker :-)

Answer (score 8):

**Check** means *to examine (something) in order to determine its accuracy, quality, or condition*.  **Check on** is a phrasal verb that means *verify, ascertain, or monitor the state or condition of*.

It's a subtle difference between the two, and, in the example you gave, I think either could be applied.

If you asked me which one was *more* correct, I think I'd vote for *check*, rather than *check on*, but that was only after consulting a dictionary.  Most tourist officers aren't that careful with their words before *checking up on* the hours of a village shop.

Oh, **check up on** means *investigate in order to establish the truth about or accuracy of*, which is, I suppose, another way of saying (nearly) the same thing.

<sub>Ref: these definitions were taken from NOAD</sub>

Comment: CED for example suggests that the usages are more closely synonymous. In "I'll check/on the fuel level", I'd say they're identical in meaning. But I'd not use "I'll check John to see if he's got enough milk" or "They'll check on his passport".  Differences in distribution and sense are subtle, and not easy to spell out in a couple of lines.

Answer (score 2):

**Check on** is used to refer to verifying the legitimacy or the condition of someone or something, according to [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/check+on).

I reckon, **check** is better suited in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are okay. For example if I worked at a hospital, I would use *check on*.

> The doctor is going to check on his patient in 10 minutes. *Meaning to monitor his state or condition*

And if I were going through a security check, I would say:

> They checked all my luggages. *Meaning to check or examine*

But in your case, both could work unless you got very picky.

Answer (score 0):

In Brit Eng, we would say *check up on smbdy/smth)* when talking about a state or process.

A bare *check* is reserved for facts and events. *Hold on, I must check if I have turned off the gas.*

*Check on* or *check up on* is better for processes and states, or for a more intensive search for information. *My aunt is ill, I'll go and check (up) on her later.* Or *I want to phone the office to check (up) on how that difficult job is going.*

I am not sure that the instant quote is a good example - a bare *check* is enough for me as the fact is easily ascertainable.