# "win" vs. "win out" in their transitive forms

Tags: word-usage

Is there a hairbreadth of difference between saying "he won the race (or the battle, the fight, etc.) and "he won out the race (...)" either in a literal or figurative sense, or does it all mean just about the same?

E.g.

> The company won the race to be first in the "smart watch" category.<sub>[source](http://tcbmag.com/Twin-Cities-Business-20th-Anniversary/Top-Five-Companies/Best-Buy)</sub>
>
> Bell only won out the race for mass installation and patent rights.>sub>[source](http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question77723.html)
>
> Luckily, my immune system won out the fight against germs.[source](http://rickyoh.blogspot.fr/2008/01/trip-tripped.html)>/sub>
>
> Schumacher has already won the fight against pneumonia.[source](http://grandprix247.com/2014/02/14/schumacher-wins-fight-against-pneumonia/)>/sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitive *win **out*** is highly non-standard...

[image]

(Clicking on the chart will show I did ask for *he won **out** the* as well - it's just too rare to graph.)

In "standard" usage, *to win out* is normally only used intransitively, to emphasize that a victory was hard-won (taking much time and/or effort)...

> *It was a lengthy struggle, [but he **won out** in the end](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but%20he%20won%20out%20in%20the%20end%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)* (as occurs hundreds of times in Google Books)

Note that although OP's cited usage is "unusual", it does occur at least a few dozen times on the Internet at large. But I doubt the equivalent [*won **through***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but%20he%20won%20out%20in%20the%20end%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22finally%20won%20through%22&tbm=bks) would *ever* be used transitively.

Comment: Thank you for contributing again. Just curious, does "win up" have any currency in spoken English (he won up the race) in analogy with other similar colloquial verbal constructions like wait up, give up (Give up the ball...give it up!), print up, check up, etc.?

Comment: @Nourished: No - so far as I know, *to win **up*** has no currency., and never has had. *Give **up*** connotes *conceding* (up = finished), and *give **it** up* approval (hands raised while clapping). [This answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73448/2637) implies *check **up** on someone* is BrE (but maybe it's also AmE) - I imagine it relates to *look up [details]*. I can't explain why people *print up/off* reports. Idiomatic usage doesn't always have any clear justification.

Comment: I thought there was another sense to "give something up". I mean -- when you ask a dog to give up the ball, isn't it just about the same as saying "give me the ball"? http://cubits.org/Dogs/thread/view/21359/

Comment: @Nourished: You're mixing up two different forms of expression. You wouldn't, for example, have asked *When you ask a dog to give the ball, isn't it just about the same as saying "give me up the ball"?* (or *give up me the ball*). But in such contexts, where ***up*** can validly be included, it more explicitly implies *conceding* (reluctantly), as I said.

Comment: Sure. However, it sounds quite logical that if you directly ask a dog to give up a ball, you mean by that to give the ball to you. In the same logic, if I bang on someone's door hollering to open up or to open up the g..... door, such a specification as "to me" likewise sounds superfluous.